# solving error in asp.net mvc visual studio 2015 with update 3

Tags: .net

This error occurs in every new project when I try to run it.

I try every thing but it isn't useful.

[image]

Comment: Please share the content of your log file.

Comment: Check the event log of your computer/server and see the real error message, that is just generic error page without information about the exception.

Comment: How can I share it?